# Testing Angular API call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

When i am trying to execute the junit, i get 1 pending spec, what is that i am missing in my junit ?

Function: This function will get all the addresses from the database

```
public getDataWithAddress(myRequest: Address): Observable<any> {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control':  'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',enter code here
      'Pragma': 'no-cache',
      'Expires': '0'
    })
  };

Address Interface:
export interface Address {
    AddressLine1?: string;
    City?: string;
    StateProvince?: string;
    PostalCode?: string;
    ReturnValues?: string;
}
```

My unit test:

```
describe('HttpService', () => {
  const address= {
    AddressLine1: '3514 W PIERCE ST',
    City: 'PHOENIX',
    StateProvince: 'AZ',
    PostalCode: '85009'
};
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ 
      HttpClientTestingModule,
      RouterTestingModule
    ],
    providers: [
      HttpService,
      DataMappingService,
      GoogleAnalyticsEventsService

    ]
  });
  service =TestBed.get(HttpService);
});

//Address
it('expect to retrun addressdata'),
      inject(
        [
          HttpTestingController,HttpService
        ],
        (httpMock: HttpTestingController, service: HttpService) =>{
                //We call service for address
          service.getDataWithAddress(address).subscribe(data => {
            expect (data).toEqual(address);
          });
    // We set the expectations for the HttpClient mock
    const req =httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:4201/api/mydata/address');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
// Then we set the fake data to be returned by the mock
    req.flush({address});
    httpMock.verify();
  });
});
```

When the test runs i get :pending specs, What am i missing here ?

Comment: Can u share screenshot of this error

Comment: expect EDL to fetch data PENDING WITH MESSAGE: Temporarily disabled with xit
get Payment History from EDL
should be created
expects hilo service to fetch data
expect Authorization
expect url
expect configuration
expect Hilo to retrun addressdata.  -----> This is greyed out
expect special fetaure codes

Comment: Use https://imgbb.com/ for the screenshot